# Why are type annotations needed on a simple Err(...) statement?

Tags: rust

```
fn some_fn(a:f32 , b: f32) -> Result<f32, &'static str> {
    if b == 0.0 {
        return Err("Error for some reason");
    }
    Ok(a / b)
}
```

This function compiles, but when I remove the return statement (just for fun)

```
fn some_fn(a:f32 , b: f32) -> Result<f32, &'static str> {
    if b == 0.0 {
        Err("Error for some reason");
    }
    Ok(a / b)
}
```

It gives the error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> main.rs:3:9
  |
3 |         Err("Error for some reason");
  |         ^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `T` declared on the enum `Result`
  |
help: consider specifying the generic arguments
  |
3 |         Err::<T, &str>("Error for some reason");
  |            +++++++++++
```

What is going on here? Because I removed the return statement, I would expect it to say "Expected Result<> found something else". What's wrong with the type inference? And the suggestion? I know I should get an error but I am confused by this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `Err` ends up nowhere. It just gets discarded right away, and either way the `Ok` gets executed and returned.

Because the `Err` value never gets returned or combined with an `Ok` value, Rust doesn't know what its `Ok` value type should be. And Rust always has to know exactly what type a variable is, even if only one part of the enum gets used.

You probably intended to write:

```rust
fn some_fn(a:f32 , b: f32) -> Result<f32, &'static str> {
    if b == 0.0 {
        Err("Error for some reason")
    } else {
        Ok(a / b)
    }
}
```

> I would expect it to say "Expected Result<> found something else"

That would only happen if you actually did something with the `Err` value. But the way you wrote it, it will just silently be discarded. You don't store it anywhere or do something with it.

Also, `Err` still is a `Result<>` type. So if anything, it would say "Expected something else, got Result<>". But I'm unsure where it would expect anything in your code, the only place it expects a `Result` is in the return value, and as you just deleted the `return`, the only thing returned is the `Ok` value, which indeed is a `Result<>` as expected.

So if you just specify the value type of your `Err`, it compiles fine:

```rust
fn some_fn(a: f32, b: f32) -> Result<f32, &'static str> {
    if b == 0.0 {
        Err::<(), _>("Error for some reason");
    }
    Ok(a / b)
}
```

Although it now gives you, as expected, the warning that the `Err` value never gets used:

```
warning: unused `Result` that must be used
 --> src/lib.rs:3:9
  |
3 |         Err::<(), _>("Error for some reason");
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_must_use)]` on by default
  = note: this `Result` may be an `Err` variant, which should be handled
```

Comment: So alright, as I understand, in this case, the compiler forgets about the Result (not correct terminology here) and thinks Err is some kind of a module or something and it wants you to pass its type?

Comment: No, not quite. It creates the `Err`, and then discards it, because you just wrote `;` after it and you don't assign (`=`) or `return` it. It is like writing `10;`. It creates a `10` value, then does nothing with it and discards it again.

Comment: *"thinks Err is some kind of module"* - no, it very well knows what `Err` is. But `Err` is of the type `Result<T, E>`, and from `Err(<&str>)` Rust is only able to deduce that the variable you are trying to create is a `Result<T, &str>`, but it doesn't know what `T` should be. That's what the error is trying to tell you. And in Rust, you can't create variables of incomplete types.

Comment: Good explanation. Appreciated

Comment: @merovingian If `Err::<(), _>(...)` confuses you; this is a partial type annotation. It tells Rust that `Err` is of the type `Result<(), E>`, and the fact that you pass a `&str` into it is enough for the compiler to deduce that it must be a `Result<(), &str>`. With the type fully resolved it can now create an object of it.